# SSRS. Specify dynamic links to reports via expression

Tags: dynamic, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-expression

I'm creating report with *Visual Studio 2013*. Here will be 1 report with links to other reports.

Report with links to other reports have following design:

```
[Name] [Description] [Instances_Count]
```

I need to make `[Name]` clickable (add action on It with link to other reports).

In preview It returning following:

```
One   This is 1 report.  3
Two   This is 2 report.  7
Three This is 3 report.  4
```

I need to make that If clicked on `One` It redirected to report with name `report_1.rdl`, the same If I click on `Two` - redirect to `report_2.rdl`

---

I need to make something like that:

`Right Click` on `[Name]` > `Properties` > `Action` > Check `Go to report`

And here I need to specify expression something like:

```
=Switch(Fields!Description.Value = "This is 1 report.", "report_1.rdl")
```

And this throws an error. I can open report with links, in this case name `One` is clickable, after clicking It redirecting to `report_1.rdl`, but after I click `View Report` (in redirected `report_1.rdl`) It **throws following error**:

> An error occured during local report processing.
>
> Error in the appliaction.
>
> Object references not set to an instance of an object.

Have you ideas how to fix this error?

*P.S. This is problem in expression. If I put link directly to any of reports It redirecting successfully. It throws an error only when I'm using this expression.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I'd try dropping the ".rdl" portion of the report name in your expression. Then I'd make sure that the expression is located in the "specify a report" box in the action tab for the placeholder. If all else fails, try using [a different method of specifying the report path.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220423.aspx)